# DetoxRuntimeError: Test Failed: First responder “(null)” does not conform to “UITextInput” protocol

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, detox

I'm run detox test with ios simulator use by expo react-native

But fill textInput by textinput() action detox has error.

Error = DetoxRuntimeError: Test Failed: First responder “(null)” does not conform to “UITextInput” protocol

`it('fill email', async () => { await element(by.text('Email')).atIndex(0).typeText('email@email.com') })`

Thank you.

environment
Detox version: 19.7.1
React Native version: 0.63.4
Node version: 16.14.1
Device model: Simulator
OS: IOS
Test-runner : jest-circus

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a couple of days ago, I only managed to solve it by changing the way of interacting with the element, instead of using by.text() implement an identifier that allows using by.id().

> it('fill email', async () => { await
> element(by.id('testID-email')).typeText('email@email.com') })

Do not forget to enable the options in the I/O option of the device simulator:
Connect hardware keyboard.